# Can we have a better summary for the [x-cart] tag (as it is useless)

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

The current summary for [x-cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x-cart) reads as follows:

> X-Cart is highly affordable, has tons of features, works as expected out of the box, and has several unique and useful features.

I'm sure that X-Cart is great and all, but *what is it* and *what does it do?*

The [wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x-cart/info) is a bit more useful, but the summary currently sounds like an advertisement. I'd edit it myself, but I honestly don't know much about X-Cart.

Can someone with some background in that tag provide a better summary (and while you're at it improve the wiki as well)?

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote; that excerpt *is* useless and falls under the "Lacks Usage Guidance" reject reason.  Granted, it's better than [the original excerpt](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7703927/revisions), but whoah, it has unique and useful features?  What product *doesn't*?  The tag wiki for it isn't much better, either.

Comment: Fixed the excerpt, but tag wiki is still bad.

Comment: @JonasCz *"X-Cart is PHP- and MySQL-based open source shopping cart system."* - That's much better, thanks!

Comment: Everyone who is viewing and upvoting this, why don't **you** help fix the tag wiki ? Take the information from the website and put together something nice and useful !